# \chaptertitle not working in scrbook with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I need to make the title of the current chapter appear in the header of my book.
With the standard class `book` I can just use `titlesec` package and `\chaptertitle`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{\sethead{}{\chaptername\ \thechapter: \chaptertitle}{}}
\pagestyle{main}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Foo}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \section{Bar}
    \lipsum[6]
    \subsection{Baz}
    \lipsum[7-10]
\end{document}
```

However, I'm using `scrbook` for the first time.
I understood that I can change the header content with package `scrlayer-scrpage`, but when I try to compile the following

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\lehead{}
\rohead{}
\chead{\chaptername~\thechapter: \chaptertitle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Foo}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \section{Bar}
    \lipsum[6]
    \subsection{Baz}
    \lipsum[7-10]
\end{document}
```

I get two errors:

```
l.19 \end
{document}
? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

? 
[2]
! Undefined control sequence.
\sls@ps@scrheadings@odd@middle@head ...aptertitle 

l.19 \end{document}

? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

?
```

If I just go on I get a document with headers without the chapter title:

[image: Header only containing "Chapter 1:"]

The problem should be in `\chaptertitle` because if I remove it the documents is compiled correctly.
I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't understand *what*.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

With `scrbook` you have to redefine `\chaptermarkformat`:

```
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername~\thechapter:\enspace}
```

Then you can use `\chead{\leftmark}`

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername~\thechapter:\enspace}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- option automark added
\ohead{}
\chead{\leftmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Bar}
\lipsum[6]
\subsection{Baz}
\lipsum[7-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]